# Drupal Antispam + Administer Views modules

Tags: views

Seems that when activating Administer Views, all pages in the path admin/content/* disappear, and got replaced by some custom views that the module automatically creates for them.

The problem is that no view is created for the antispam moderation queue page...

So i was wondering if any of you had the same problem and how did you solve it?

I tried to disable the antispam module and activating it again, so it load later than the admin views... a crazy idea that accomplished nothing...

I tried to create a system view to emulate the capabilities of the antispam page... but i don't know how to get the comments marked as spam from a view... it doesn't seem to exist any field used as a flag for that...

Any ideas?

Thank you very much,
Marc